# How can I permanently change my keyboard model and language in Lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, configuration

I thought this would be trivial, but after two hours of googling and experimenting still nothing works.

I want to use the ROS+Kinetic-lxde o/s sd image for the Raspberry Pi.  As far as I can tell this is Lubuntu. Unfortunately the keyboard layout in the image does not match my keyboard, so I need to change it.

So far I have tried localectl from the command line.  That does not do anything. I tried localectl list-keymaps and that says it can't find any console keymaps.

I added the 'Keyboard Layout Handler' applet to the task bar and set the keyboard through that.  My changes were lost when I rebooted.

I tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration.  That let me set up the keyboard, but again the changes were lost after a reboot.

I tried editing the file /etc/default/keyboard, but that already had the correct settings and they are doing no good.

So, how can I permanently set the keyboard type ?  It seems crazy that it can't be done easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here details from the [Lubuntu/Keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard#Change_Layout_Option) article section *Keyboard Mapping*:

> The simple way to do this is to launch Lxkeymap (under Preferences.)

It's likely that `/etc/defaults/keyboard` defines the default keyboard layout used by the *system* and X server, but it's possible that Lubuntu's desktop environment (LXDE) has it's own configuration files that override that.